# Passing Arabic values in parameters results in % spaces

Tags: php, htaccess, url-encoding

I have built an *.htaccess* clean URL, this part works perfect in my *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /road.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule . نقفورالثانيفوكاس/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^نقفورالثانيفوكاس/$ road.php [L]
```

But this part in the parameters is producing spaces in my navigation:

```
<?php
$tit = urlencode("نقفورالثاني-فوكاس");
$cap = urlencode("الطريق-للقمة");
?>
<a href = '<?php echo "road.php?title=$tit&caption=$cap" ; ?>'>
```

Only choosing *road.php* is working:

```
http://www.nikephorosphokas.com/%D9%86%D9%82%D9%81%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%81%D9%88%D9%83%D8%A7%D8%B3/
```

(The title is displaying great in Arabic, so this is working)

But with the two parameters, it's resulting in a lot of spaces:

```
http://www.nikephorosphokas.com/%D9%86%D9%82%D9%81%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%81%D9%88%D9%83%D8%A7%D8%B3/%25D9%2586%25D9%2582%25D9%2581%25D9%2588%25D8%25B1%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25AB%25D8%25A7%25D9%2586%25D9%258A%25D9%2581%25D9%2588%25D9%2583%25D8%25A7%25D8%25B3/%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25B7%25D8%25B1%25D9%258A%25D9%2582%25D9%2584%25D9%2584%25D9%2582%25D9%2585%25D8%25A9/
```

(This is not what I want, so it's NOT working)

This is my complete *.htaccess*:

```
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /road.php\s [NC]
  RewriteRule . نقفورالثانيفوكاس/ [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^نقفورالثانيفوكاس/$ road.php [L]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /road.php\?title=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
  RewriteRule . نقفورالثانيفوكاس/%1/? [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /road.php\?title=([^&\s]+)&caption=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
  RewriteRule . نقفورالثانيفوكاس/%1/%2/? [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule ^نقفورالثانيفوكاس/([^/]+)/$ road.php?title=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^نقفورالثانيفوكاس/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ road.php?title=$1&caption=$2 [L]


  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

I tried adding *urlendice* or *rawurlencode* as well, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you have to use PunyCode encoded addresses in .htaccess file. Try to convert arabic values to punycode with a tool such as this one: http://www.punycoder.com/

I have done it this way for Cyrillic addresses and it worked fine.